# Dont allow to show html tag while appending to div or span

Tags: angularjs

When I am going to bind data in angularjs variable like..

```
$scope.msg = '<div class="success_msg">Message</div>';

<span ng-bind="msg"></span>
```

but its show with div tab also. I dont want to show html elements. I want to show only Message in this span.
What is the solution?

Comment: Why can't you just set `$scope.msg = 'Message'`?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to bind html fragments, you have to use mg-bind-html.
You can find the documentation here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

(don't forget to add ngSanitize to your module dependencies)